# скопировать данные из контейнера без id и вставить в input

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо взять данные из `<div contenteditable="plaintext-only">Москва</div>` и вставить в input с `id="cascoon-autocomplete_2"`

Я пробовал через input value, но не получилось

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_ru").oninput = () => {
      const input = document.getElementById('flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_ru');
      const output = document.getElementById('cascoon-autocomplete_2');
    
      output.value = input.value;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: А не может это быть [Shadow DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom)? Если так, то получать доступ к теневому древу нужно через shadowRoot элемента.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```
document.getElementById("flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_ru").oninput = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('[contenteditable=plaintext-only]');
    const output = document.getElementById('cascoon-autocomplete_2');
    output.textContent = input.textContent;
}
```

Comment: не работает так

Answer (score 1):

> Необходимо взять данные из Москва и вставить в input с id="cascoon-autocomplete_2"

Например вот так...

Если у тебя такое не работает - значит придется тебе делать нормальный тестовый пример вместо фотки.

```js
const v = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="plaintext-only"]').textContent
document.querySelector('#cascoon-autocomplete_2').textContent = v
```

```html
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only">Москва</div>
<p id="cascoon-autocomplete_2"></p>
```